# Debugging Windows Phone App on device - no stack trace

Tags: debugging, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, visual-studio-debugging

When I debug an app on my device with Windows Phone 8.1 the second time I run debugging session stack trace and variables data is not available.

If I uninstall app and run debugging first fresh time, it works as expected, variables data is present.
The next time I start debugging it disappear.

Looks like Visual Studio does not deploy PDBs if app is already installed.

Who knows how to fix this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32598151/on-windows-phone-step-over-exits-from-async-method-when-i-step-over-async-meth/33192942#33192942
Solution is the same.