# On Windows Phone "Step Over" exits from async method when I step over async method call with await

Tags: debugging, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, visual-studio-debugging

While debugging Windows Phone 8.1 app on device, "Step Over" exits from async method when I step over async method call with await.
This does not happen in Windows 8.1 or desktop apps but in Windows Phone apps.

Why does this happen?

Comment: u sure its not throwing an exception inside the method ?

Comment: Yes even though method executes successfully it steps out

Answer (score 2):

This problem was caused by disabled option **Suppress JIT optimization on module load**.

Explained in [JIT Optimization and Debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241594.aspx) on MSDN